Auto Key object controlled by NodeOSC
I have a empty and its location is controlled by a values coming from NodeOSC add:on (connected to an EEG device)
I want to auto key the empty so I can reuse the locations after I turn the NodeOSC server off (and render them fully)
Oddly, I can't auto any data from the empty when NodeOSC is running and in control of the empty.

I want to do this as well and have not yet found a solution. Perhaps you could use the empty with a constraint to affect another object and auto key that object? Edit I just tried this and it doesn’t seem to work. Obviously the add-on needs to have native support created for this.
